# Based on Newton's law of universal gravitation: How fast does any gravitational disturbance propagate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, causality, speed

Based on Newton's law of universal gravitation: How fast does any gravitational disturbance propagate?

Comment: According to the classical physics, the disturbance propagates instantanteneously

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Newton's law does not specify or predict any propagation speed for gravitational disturbances at all. As a nonrelativistic treatment of gravity, it implicitly assumes infinite speed. Einstein's development of general relativity does specify the speed of light as the propagation speed for gravitational disturbances.